# How to create a function to read the current single row from a csv file whenever it will be called from main function or main loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to write a python script. The python script consists of two functions one is the main function and another is subfunction. The function of this subfunction is to read the current single row from CSV file return this row values to the main function or main loop whenever it will be called from the main function or main loop and increment the row counter such that whenever it will be called again in next, it can return the next row values.

For that, I have developed this python script using `Pandas` Module but it returns all rows at a time but I want single row at a time, the `time.sleep(10)` is not working here. I am new in Python as well as Pandas please suggest me how could I proceed to get the exact result what I want.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import time

 def readCsv():
   i = 0
   data = pd.read_csv("/home/oztron/Documents/energylogger2.csv")
   t = data.iloc[i:,0]
   e = data.iloc[i:,1]
   p = data.iloc[i:,2]
   v = data.iloc[i:,3]
   c = data.iloc[i:,4]
   i = i + 1
   return t, e, p, v, c

 while True:
   a, b, c, d ,e = readCsv()
   print(a)
   time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I wanted to read an only single row from dataframe at a time. Like this way whenever the `readCsv()` function will be called it will read the first row of the data frame and returns its value, not all rows, then when it will be called the second time it will return the sends row's values only.

Comment: Did yout try the python keyword `yield` instead of `return`?

Comment: Remove the colons from your index `data.iloc[i:,3]` -> `data[i,3]`.

Comment: Put `i` outside the scope of your function, e.g., pass it in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs a basic tutorial. I would not normally vote to close because of this, but the canned response to legitimate answers, indicating shifting requirements, makes me think that answering the question won't help much.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Can you use csv module instead of pandas? If so:

```
import csv

with open('/home/oztron/Documents/energylogger2.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in content:
        t, e, p, v, c = row
        print(t, e, p, v, c)
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I wanted to read an only single row from dataframe at a time. Like this way whenever the `readCsv()` function will be called it will read the first row of the data frame and returns its value, not all rows, then when it will be called the second time it will return the sends row's values only.

Comment: @Prayuktibid. This code does exactly what your question asks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do by reading each row here. But there are other pythonic ways of doing this. Firstly, once you read a csv using pandas it is read completely as a dataframe. You can use pandas.DataFrame.iterrows() if you want to access each row of this dataframe.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("/home/oztron/Documents/energylogger2.csv")
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row[1])
```

It will print all the values in the second column (as python uses zero-based indexing).

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I wanted to read an only single row from dataframe at a time. Like this way whenever the `readCsv()` function will be called it will read the first row of the data frame and returns its value, not all rows, then when it will be called the second time it will return the sends row's values only.

Comment: @Prayuktibid. Judging from your original code and your responses to the answers, you need to spend some time reading up on iteration and indexing in Python and then on pandas. Both answers here are valid solutions to your stated problem.